# Why reduce input records is greater than map output records?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I ran some Job on Hadoop and puzzled by this question.
I am attaching a screenshot from jobtracker. In addition, the difference varies from run to run and is sometimes absent.
[image]

Combiner is not used in this case